# is there a way to see the raycast you put out into your scene in ursina?

Tags: python, game-engine, game-development, ursina

is there a way to see the raycasts you put out in the scene?
I imagine if there is a way its pretty simple, but I can't seem to find it.
its not 100% necessary, but it would make experimenting with this engine easier and funner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use `debug=True`

Example:

```py
hit_info = raycast(Vec3(0,0,0), Vec3(0,0,1), distance=5, debug=True)
```

Comment: yea, I figured it was something simple like that. Thank you.